# How do you look for a condition in a range and then get info from another range into a single cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So at the moment I have a working code to get multiple items in a cell following a condition

My code is:

```
=Contatenate(
IF('Sheet1'!E3 = "R",'sheet1'!A3,""), "                  ",
IF('Sheet1'!E4 = "R",'sheet1'!A4,""), "                  ",
```

and so on.....

it then returns every name that meets this condition.

I was just wondering if there was a quicker way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: TEXTJOIN should be useful.

Comment: Ah thanks @BigBen I used =ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN("                                      ",TRUE,IF('Contact & Overview'!E103:E122="R",'Contact & Overview'!A103:A122,""))) and worked like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the solution as an answer to make it more clear:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF('Contact & Overview'!E103:E122="R",'Contact & Overview'!A103:A122,"")))
```

---

From Sheets [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en):

**Sample Usage**

```
TEXTJOIN(“ “, TRUE, “hello”, “world”)
TEXTJOIN(“, ”, FALSE, A1:A5)
```

**Syntax**

`TEXTJOIN(delimiter, ignore_empty, text1, [text2, ...])`